# Is there a way to define C language macro in Android.bp file?

Tags: android, android-vts

I want to know if I can define C language macro in Android.bp file ? I am wrapping unit tests of some modules (which are written in C++) into VTS framework. There are certain changes which needs to be protected under macro.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a define to the `cflags` in your `Android.bp` to be checked in your test code.

```
cc_binary {
    [...]
    cflags: [ "-DMYUNITTEST" ]
}
```

```c
#ifndef MYUNITTEST
// not to be used in this unittest.
#endif
```